# insert the rows with radio button into database table in php

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a table that shows all courses of a student in courses.php file. I take the information of all courses row by row from a database table and show it in courses.php page. Each row has a radio button but how many row will be in the table is not known. According to each row taken from database table, I should create a unique radio button. When I select some of the rows with radio button, it should insert the checked rows into a different database table and show it in the table taken_courses.php. How do I control which buttons is selected?

Answer (score 0):

User `checkbox` rather

Add a checkbox in your html code in row

```
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="<?php echo $row['course_id']; ?>" />
```

and in your php get them by

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['course'] as $course) {
    echo $course;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

name="course[]"  this is ok. when i clicked submit button below the table, it should insert the selected row with checkbox into the database table. Not show like "echo $course"

Comment: echo is just to show that you can access that data this way, you can use `$course` and add in the database,, whats the big deal?